# Why it is not called select-property in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

An example

`get-process | select-object vm, cpu,id | out-gridview`

Here `select-object` actually is selecting `PROPERTIES` of the `OBJECTS` in the `COLLECTION` stored in memory.

Anyone knows why this cmdlet is not called `select-property` ?

Maybe I m asking a noob quesiton......

Comment: With everything in Powershell consisting of objects, it seems to make sense for consistency purposes to name the cmdlet as `select-object` when the purpose of this cmdlet is to access properties on the given object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call Select-Object Blah, Blah1, Blah2, you are using the Property parameter via positional binding

Notice that the help describes a lot more than just the -Property parameter you are using:

```
Get-Help Select-Object -Full

<# 
    ...
    The Select-Object cmdlet selects specified properties of an object or set 
    of objects. It can also select unique objects, a specified number of 
    objects, or objects in a specified position in an array.

    To select objects from a collection, use the First, Last, Unique, Skip, and 
    Index parameters. To select object properties, use the Property parameter. 
    When you select properties, Select-Object returns new objects that have 
    only the specified properties.
#>
```

Spend some time using the built in help system, there is a trove of information in there!

```
#Get the full help details
Get-Help Select-Object -Full

#If available, look online for help
Get-Help Select-Object -Online

#List conceptual topics
Get-Help about_*

#Read about regular expressions
Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions
```

Lastly, if you're talking semantics, the noun in a PowerShell command name refers to what your verb is acting upon:  objects.

Cheers!

Comment: Ha, that's why, `It can also select unique objects, a specified number of objects, or objects in a specified position in an array.To select object properties, use the Property parameter.`. Thanks